# Highcharts solid gauge stacked values

Tags: highcharts, gauge

I have a nice gauge that displays a percentage value like so:

[image: solid gauge]

The options are:

```
{
  title: false,
  legend: false,
  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
  },
  pane: {
    size: '100%',
    startAngle: 0,
    background: {
      backgroundColor: '#eee',
      outerRadius: '100%',
      innerRadius: '60%',
      borderWidth: 0,
      shape: 'arc',
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorTickInterval: null,
    tickPixelInterval: 400,
    tickWidth: 0,
    title: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    labels: {
        enabled:false
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
      dataLabels: {
        y: -15,
        borderWidth: 0,
        format: '{y}%',
        style: {
          fontSize: '1rem',
          fontWeight: 'normal',
        }
      },
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 75,
      color: cyan,
    }]
  }]
}
```

But now I need two values:

[image: solid gauge two values]

I'd have expected to add some `stacking` option somewhere, along with something like:

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 10,
      color: blue,
    }, {
      y: 65,
      color: cyan,
    }]
  }]
```

but it doesn't work. And I haven't found any example for this use-case over the internet either. :(

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @magdalena said, unfortunately there is no `stacking` option in a `solidgauge` chart :(

I succeeded to fake this by applying the following transformation:

```
const absoluteValues = [{
  y: 75,
  color: 'cyan',
},
    {
  y: 15,
  color: 'blue',
}];

const options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'My serie',
    data: [].concat(absoluteValues).reduce((acc, val) => {
      return [...acc, {
        ...val,
        y: acc.reduce((result, {y}) => result + y, val.y),
      }]
    }, []).reverse()
  }],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no stacking option for `soliidgague`. You need to count expected values by yourself to achieve the effect from provided image:

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 75,
      color: 'cyan',
    },
        {
      y: 15,
      color: 'blue',
    }]
  }]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4zq6ehfj/

Answer (score 0):

```
  series: [
{
  name: 'Operating Systems',
  data: [{ y: 10, color: white, }]
  size: '60%'
},
{
  name: 'Browsers',
  data: [{ y: 10, color: blue, }],
  size: '80%',

}, {
  name: 'Versions',
  data: [{ y: 65, color: cyan, }],
  size: '100%',
  
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but your solution doesn't work: the arcs seem to superpose themselves.